# How to change frequency of automatic backups in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I recently noticed [unexpected charges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdL9C.png) on my AWS bill related to RDS backups, even though I haven't actively used RDS, only EC2 where i have postgresql container. [screen of RDS dashboard where's no instances or anything else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x824J.png)

I discovered that the charges were attributed to automatic backups in EC2. It seems that these backups are triggering RDS backup-related fees, but I can't find where I can disable this (for example, in rds there's no backups, snapshots or database instances so I can't manage it from here). Can someone guide me through the process of changing the backup frequency in EC2? Any insights or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What you showed is that you have a RDS instance for PostgreSQL... When creating/modifying the instance, you can choose a number of days that you want automatic backups to be available.

Comment: @Caldazar I know, but I wrote in my question that I didn't create this instance

Comment: EC2 does not trigger RDS charges. If you're getting billed for RDS, then you or someone else using this account created an RDS instance, and perhaps later deleted it.  If that's truly not the case, then you should open a support ticket, as that represents a bigger issue on AWS's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a RDS postgress instance running in the Stockholm region. Switch regions on the RDS page from Frankfurt to Stockholm and you should see the instance and its snapshots.